# Warning: next-head-count is missing

Tags: javascript, next.js, head

I'm using a custom _document.js from [Next documentation.](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) In result, I keep getting a warning message printed out to the console. I've tried to restart my server and emptied my browser's cache. My _document.js is inside a "pages" folder as it should be. I made sure that the file is being readen by adding some tags to my `<Head>` and inspecting my website to see if the tag is being added to the `<Head>`. (My website is working correctly I'm just tired of this warning message.)

Console warning:

```
Warning: next-head-count is missing. https://err.sh/next.js/next-head-count-missing
```

This is my _document.js file:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Comment: Your `_document.js` looks fine to me. Have you tried removing the `.next` folder and start the dev server again?

Comment: I tried removing node_modules and .next folders. I just found a solution and posted it below. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I had a `<head>` tag inside index.html as well. After removing it the error was gone. There is nothing wrong with my _document.js. I was importing style in a separate `<head>` inside index.js, that's why the error occurred.

Solution: I moved `<head>` content from index.js to _document.js and removed the `<head>` tag from index.js.

Comment: i have the same issue but this solution doesn't work for me...any suggestions ?

Comment: In my case I had a `<html lang={lang}/>` inside a `next/head` Head element. apparently is not supported, to change the lang attribute.

Comment: Hey @itsjavi were you able to figure out an alternative to that? facing the same issue

Answer (score 12):

This error also shows up when an unsupported html tag is entered added into the `<Head>` tag.

In my case I had accidentally added a `<p>...</p>` tag within the `<Head>...</Head>` tag in a component, which was throwing this error.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was related to the `<html lang="en" />` inside the  `<Head>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was an incorrect html tag inside next's **Head** component. 90% of this error means that something wrong with the content inside **Head**. Try to remove elements inside **Head** one by one and you will find what causes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Head component imported from next/Document was in the custom _document, but it was within the body tag, moving it within the Html component and outside of the body tag fixed it.

```
// Incorrect
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render (): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Html>
        <body>
          <Head />
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}


// Correct
export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render (): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case "Convert HTML to JSX" vscode extension added a wrapper div tag in the next/head component. I removed div tag and the warning gone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a custom component `<MobileView>` in the `<Head>`.
So changing that did the trick.